# Kendo Grid, locked columns and print preview in Firefox

Tags: kendo-ui

If you do a print preview on a grid with locked columns in Firefox you can get some odd issues, this is probably because it's a 3 tables in one

e.g. non aligned columns, page breaks after the header, etc

If Firefox ever supports "page-break-inside: avoid;" this may not be needed

A workaround in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit messy but you can clean it as you like. As this requires recreating the grid it's only useful if the grid is suitably small and gets it's data via json or similar

(1) Wire into the print event using the below, notice the flag getting set

```
(function ()
{
    var beforePrint = function ()
    {
        PrintPreProcess();
    };

    if (window.matchMedia)
    {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql)
        {
            if (mql.matches)
            {
                beforePrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
} ());

var PrintPreProcessInProgress = false;

function PrintPreProcess()
{
    window.PrintPreProcessInProgress = true;

    $.event.trigger(
        "PrintPreviewStarted",
        {
        }
    );

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        window.PrintPreProcessInProgress = false;

        $.event.trigger(
            "PrintPreviewEnded",
            {
            }
        );
    }, 0);
}
```

(2) Redraw the grid when print preview starts and ends

```
    $(document).on("PrintPreviewStarted", function (e, args)
    {
        ReDrawGrid();
    });

    $(document).on("PrintPreviewEnded", function (e, args)
    {
        ReDrawGrid();
    });
```

(3) As part of the redraw, only allow locked columns if not in print preview, i.e.

```
locked: colModel.Locked && !window.PrintPreProcessInProgress,
```